# How do i turn `[(1, 'item1'),(2, "item2"),(2, "item3"),(3, "item4"),(2, "item5")]` into a JSON tree and HTML tree in python?

Tags: python, html, json, tree

I've been going back and forth on this for hours, and i just can't seem to do it.

I've been trying to split the problem into if statements like if previous number < number then create a child group and then go through it but i've been having troubles wrapping my head around a way to move through the tree easily. I would of thought that there would be tools for json that would allow me to do this, but i can't seem to find any.

I'd like to turn a list of tuples like  `[(1, 'item1'),(2, "item2"),(2, "item3"),(3, "item4"),(2, "item5")]` into JSON and HTML.
I don't think i was clear at explaining the format of the tree so I'll go into further detail.
Each number represents the level of the nodes, and it's ordered, so it should probably be a tuple.
It was being displayed as `print '\t' * indent`

```
Item1
    Item2
    Item3
        Item4
    Item5
```

Whenever the number increments all the items with the increment are the child of the previous number.

```
Item1
    Child of Item1
    Child Item2
        Child of item2
        Child Item3
            Child of Item 3
        Child of item2
    Child of Item 1
```

When you put this ordered list together you can turn it into a Json tree Like the following, which is what i'm working towards.

```
{
 "name": "item1",
 "children": [
  {"name": "item2"}
  {
   "name": "item3",
   "children": [
     {"name": "item4"}
   ]
  }
  {"name": "item5"}
 ]
}
```

and HTML tree

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li><span>item</span>
            <ul>
                <li>item2</li>
                <li><span>item3</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>item4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>item5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It needs to take x number of items.

Comment: The logic of how to turn the list into the tree is not clear. What do the numbers stand for?

Comment: @DimitriSchachmann Think they denote each item's level - see my answer

Comment: @enigma but a tree topology is not well defined by just specifying the levels for each item. How do I know whether item4 is the child of item2 or item3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is quite recursive, but gives you your desired result as JSON. If this is acceptable, I shall look into generating similar HTML.

```
data = [(1, 'item1'), (2, "item2"), (2, "item3"), (3, "item4"), (2, "item5")]

import json


class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.level = parent.level + 1 if parent else 0
        self.children = []

    def to_json_obj(self):
        if len(self.children):
            return {'name': self.name, 'children': [child.to_json_obj() for child in self.children]}
        else:
            return {'name': self.name}


def data_to_json(data):
    tree = Entity()
    current = tree
    for item in data:
        if item[0] > current.level:
            pass
        else:
            while True:
                current = current.parent
                if current.level == item[0] - 1:
                    break
        new = Entity(item[1], current)
        current.children.append(new)
        current = new
    return json.dumps(tree.to_json_obj()["children"][0], indent=2)

print data_to_json(data)
```

gives the output

```
{
  "name": "item1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "item2"
    },
    {
      "name": "item3",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "item4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "item5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. This works beautifully. And from that i was able to put together a simple solution to generate the html version. Thank you so much.

Comment: @raz Great! If the answer is acceptable to you, you can accept it by clicking the tick on the left by the voting buttons. Enjoy coding!